# How references are really implemented in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I would like to know how references are really implemented in C++.
I mean, initialization of a réference? 
Is it more efficient to handle a reference or a pointer?

for example:

```
int i = 7;
int &j = i;   // how is this ligne compiled?
int *k = &i;  // is it less efficient doing this?
```

And is the case of objets, is there any diffrence in managing reference?

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't say how references are implemented.

Comment: Most compilers will just make a note that `i` and `j` mean the same thing and not generate any code for that.

Comment: OP is thinking of C++ as a one-to-one translation of machine code, rather than as a description of a program semantics. OP should stop doing that.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition, I understand. But I wanted to know if it is more efficient to use references or pointers.

Comment: Most compilers implement reference as `constant-pointers` i.e. `int & j = i;` would be treated as `int * const ptr = &i;`. Now, `ptr` can't be modified which we want here because references can't be reassigned. But this is universal behavior of all compilers !!

Comment: You should not use a reference over a pointer to gain performance, even if it would be faster (which i doubt). You should choose what you use by the semantics of your target.
If you do not own the target, and do not need to change the pointer, take a reference.

Comment: @watou: Your question shows that you don't.